# Check if php string is alphanumeric including Cyrillic characters?

Tags: php

I have found a lot of different patterns on the net (tested them all), i have also added encoding to the page, but nothing seams to work. This is my code:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>

<body>
<?php



$teststring="cc12cž";


$pattern  = "/^[p{L}\p{M}\a-zA-Z*0-9\s\-]+$/u";
if(preg_match($pattern, $teststring))
    {echo"IT IS ALFANUMERIC";}
else
    {echo"ERROR";}


?>

</body></html>
```

This is what i tried

```
//$pattern  = "/^[\p{L}\p{M}\a-zA-Z*0-9\s\-]+$/u"; 
//$pattern  = "/^[p{L}\p{M}\a-zA-Z*0-9\s\-]+$/u"
//$pattern  ='/^[a-zA-Z\p{Cyrillic}\d\s\-]+$/u'
//$pattern  ="/(*UTF8)^[[:alnum:]]+$/"
//$pattern  ="/^[a-zA-Z\p{Cyrillic}\p{Cyrillic}]+$/u"
```

Comment: @CharlotteDunois that is the start of line, it would have to be in the char set to negate it.

Comment: On regex101 `ž` doesn't get highlighted as part of your search string. That means your whole regex fails due to that one character. https://regex101.com/r/iY8cM3/1

Comment: @DanielA.White Yup, my fault.

Comment: Put a backslash before `p{L}` and it works then. https://regex101.com/r/iY8cM3/3

Comment: Just tried with   $pattern  = "/^[\p{L}\p{M}\a-zA-Z*0-9\s\-]+$/u"; still wont work.

Comment: And even my old pattern is showing bad bihavior !

Comment: `ž` is not a cyrillic character, more like a polish character, which is the standard alphabet with some more accents. This is cyrillic: на здоровье

Comment: How about using `mb_ereg` instead of preg_match?

Comment: @Elzo Valugi Still nothing with mb_ereg.

Comment: @maraca ž-> in some Balkan countries it is regular letter in aplhabet latin-cirilic. And на здоровье ofcourse :)

Answer (score 3):

I did a test using ZF [Zend_Validate_Alnum](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.validate.set.html) and your string seems to validate correctly.

```
$validator = new Zend_Validate_Alnum();
if ($validator->isValid('cc12cž')) {
    // value contains only allowed chars
    echo "IT IS ALFANUMERIC";
} else {
    echo "ERROR";
}
```

From what I see [their validation technique](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/master/library/Zend/Validate/Alnum.php#L119) is quite simple and it does not involve `regexp`:

```
if (!is_string($value) && !is_int($value) && !is_float($value)) {
    $this->_error(self::INVALID);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have used the provided function. Is it possible to add check if there are special characters and return false if there are. Because now it will return true even for a string like this
"%$##@@!@$%+_{}|??123>><"

Comment: @Dime so you first check if the string is Alnum using this method. if this passes you can add another check using regex or a list with other chars that you don't want - an exclusion rule.